What is the Benefit of "ToolTip.UseAnimation" in C# WinForm?
Whether ToolTip.UseAnimation is true or false it does not make any change !
Can someone give me a simple code example to show its usage ?
and if it make fading effect so what's the difference between it and Fading Property ?
i've already google it and used Chat-GPT and saw Microsoft C# Ref. for it but couldn't understand its benefit or how to use it and show its effect to the user.

UseAnimation causes sort of a slide effect (default behavior, most visible when the popup appears), UseFading is the classic fading effect (default behavior, in/out, most visible when the popup disappears). Slight difference when ComCtl32 v.6 is used (mostly caused by TTF_TRANSPARENT)

First, Thanks for replying.
Second,
Sorry, i didn't go that depth with C# but what i could understand is that UseAnimation make a sliding effect but only in case of using a file called "ComCtl32.dll" Version-6 ! right ?

i don't know what "TTF_TRANSPARENT" should be !


The animation is always present, it can behave differently depending on the System version and the ComCtl32 version in use (the latter can be specified in the manifest). After you have created a ToolTip, you have to register a tool that will use the ToolTip (this is done internally, of course, in the .NET component), sending a TTM_ADDTOOL message to the ToolTip, along with a TTTOOLINFO struct with the specifics (see its members)
